# Custom serializer issue in django with json data

Tags: python, json, django, django-serializer

I cant get my serializer to work correctly on a foreign key field any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the error

dim_json = DimensionSerializer(dim_data)

print dim_json

DimensionSerializer([, , , , , ]):

```
id = IntegerField(label='ID', read_only=True) 

   description = CharField(max_length=255) 

   style = CharField(max_length=255) 

   created_at = DateField() 

   updated_at = DateField()

   target = IntegerField() 

   upper_limit = IntegerField() 

   lower_limit = IntegerField() 

   inspection_tool = CharField(max_length=255) 

   critical = IntegerField() 

   units = CharField(max_length=255) 

   metric = CharField(max_length=255) 

   target_strings = CharField(max_length=255) 

   ref_dim_id = IntegerField() 

   nested_number = IntegerField() 

   met_upper = IntegerField() 

   met_lower = IntegerField() 

   valc = CharField(max_length=255) 

   sheet = PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Sheet.objects.all(), required=False)
```

serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers 
from app.models import Dimension, Sheet, Customer 

class DimensionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer): 
  description = serializers.CharField(max_length=255) 
  style = serializers.CharField(max_length=255) 
  created_at = serializers.DateField() 
  updated_at = serializers.DateField() 
  target = serializers.IntegerField() 
  upper_limit = serializers.IntegerField() 
  lower_limit = serializers.IntegerField() 
  inspection_tool = serializers.CharField(max_length=255) 
  critical = serializers.IntegerField() 
  units = serializers.CharField(max_length=255) 
  metric = serializers.CharField(max_length=255) 
  target_strings = serializers.CharField(max_length=255) 
  ref_dim_id = serializers.IntegerField() 
  nested_number = serializers.IntegerField() 
  #position = serializers.IntegerField() 
  met_upper = serializers.IntegerField() 
  met_lower = serializers.IntegerField() 
  valc = serializers.CharField(max_length=255) 
  #if found this with a google search but still does not work and continues to give error. ..... 
  sheet = SheetSerializer(many=True) 
  class Meta: 
    model = Dimension 
    read_only_fields = ('id', 'created_at', 'updated_at', 'posistion', sheet) 



class SheetSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer): 
  create_date = serializers.DateField() 
  updated_date = serializers.DateField() 
  customer_name = serializers.CharField(max_length=255) 
  part_number = serializers.CharField(max_length=255) 
  part_revision = serializers.CharField(max_length=255) 
  work_order = serializers.CharField(max_length=255) 
  purchase_order = serializers.CharField(max_length=255) 
  sample_size = serializers.IntegerField() 
  sample_scheme = serializers.CharField(max_length=255) 
  overide_scheme = serializers.IntegerField() 
  template = serializers.IntegerField() 
  sample_schem_percent = serializers.IntegerField() 
  critical_dimensions = serializers.IntegerField() 
  closed = serializers.IntegerField() 
  serial_index = serializers.CharField(max_length=255) 
  drawing_number = serializers.CharField(max_length=255) 
  drawing_revision = serializers.CharField(max_length=255) 
  heat_number = serializers.CharField(max_length=255) 
  note = serializers.CharField(max_length=255) 
  valc = serializers.CharField(max_length=255) 
  customer = CustomerSerializer(many=True) 
  class Meta: 
    model = Sheet 
    read_only_fields = ('id', 'create_date', 'updated_at') 


class CustomerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer): 
  customer_id = serializers.IntegerField() 
  customer_name = serializers.CharField(max_length=255) 
  created_at = serializers.DateField() 
  updated_at = serializers.DateField()
```

models.py

```
class Dimension(models.Model): 
  description = models.CharField(max_length=255) 
  style = models.CharField(max_length=255) 
  created_at = models.DateField() 
  updated_at = models.DateField() 
  target = models.IntegerField() 
  upper_limit = models.IntegerField() 
  lower_limit = models.IntegerField() 
  inspection_tool = models.CharField(max_length=255) 
  critical = models.IntegerField() 
  units = models.CharField(max_length=255) 
  metric = models.CharField(max_length=255) 
  target_strings = models.CharField(max_length=255) 
  ref_dim_id = models.IntegerField() 
  nested_number = models.IntegerField() 

  met_upper = models.IntegerField() 
  met_lower = models.IntegerField() 
  valc = models.CharField(max_length=255) 
  sheet = models.ForeignKey(Sheet, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=DEFAULT_FOREIGN_KEY) 


class Customer(models.Model): 
  objects = CustomerManager() 
  customer_id = models.IntegerField() 
  customer_name = models.CharField(max_length=255) 
  created_at = models.DateField 
  updated_at = models.DateField 


class Sheet(models.Model): 
  objects = SheetManager() 

  create_date = models.DateField() 
  updated_date = models.DateField() 
  customer_name = models.CharField(max_length=255) 
  part_number = models.CharField(max_length=255) 
  part_revision = models.CharField(max_length=255) 
  work_order = models.CharField(max_length=255) 
  purchase_order = models.CharField(max_length=255) 
  sample_size = models.IntegerField() 
  sample_scheme = models.CharField(max_length=255) 
  overide_scheme = models.IntegerField() 
  template = models.IntegerField() 
  sample_schem_percent = models.IntegerField() 
  critical_dimensions = models.IntegerField() 
  closed = models.IntegerField() 
  serial_index = models.CharField(max_length=255) 
  drawing_number = models.CharField(max_length=255) 
  drawing_revision = models.CharField(max_length=255) 
  heat_number = models.CharField(max_length=255) 
  note = models.CharField(max_length=255) 
  valc = models.CharField(max_length=255) 
  customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=DEFAULT_FOREIGN_KEY)
```

Comment: change formatting, please.

Comment: @giosans that is done

Comment: @Snowman08 look at top of your question change that too please

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out instead of using my custom serializer I just used the django.core one and presto it works.

```
dim_json = serializer.serialize('json', Dimension.objects.all())

print dim_json
```